# How to use jq to get a value of decimal/number type from a JSON response which is not surrounded by " "

Tags: json, linux, shell, sh, jq

I am new to shell scripting and I need some help.
I am trying to use jq to get values from a api response and check for its correctness.

Here is a sample for how the response looks like,

```
    {
      "data" : {
        "transactionType" : "Sales",
        "transactionSubType" : "DomesticSale",
        "Items" : [ {
          "itemID" : "2",
          "itemType" : "Good",
          "amount" : 5.0,
          "tax" : 1.0        
        } ]
     }
}
```

I am able to get the values for transactionType or transactionsubtype or even ItemID values etc as given below

```
jq '.data.transactionType'    
jq '.data.Items[0].itemID'
```

for Transaction type and item id

but when it comes to values of numeric types i.e., without the quotes in it, I don't get any value. 
I am using similar syntax for the numeric type also as shown below.

```
jq '.data.Items[0].amount'
jq '.data.Items[0].tax'
```

Please help!!!

Comment: your input json lacks a trailing `}`

Answer (score 3):

Your jq invocations are fine, but the sample data is missing a final closing brace ("}"), so perhaps you were not feeding jq properly.

If you're wondering why you didn't see an error message, it's almost certainly because jq 1.5 is not very good about handling incomplete JSON. The problem has since been fixed at "master".  With the current version, you'd see something like this:

```
parse error: Unfinished JSON term at EOF at line 15, column 0
```

Comment: Sorry abt that... I just shared a small part of the actual file and also modified it just to make the structure similar to the actual response i am using. sharing original data is prohibited so had to make changes like that. But the file i am using is not incomplete or erroneous.. I also added the brace here.

Comment: We've tested your jq queries using the corrected JSON, so if you are having problems, you're going to have to provide more information, e.g. which version of jq you're using, and what platform.  A complete and convincing typescript might also help.

Comment: I am using jq 1.4 on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I've checked there's no problem with your sample data, using jq 1.4.  In the Q, please add a section showing a typescript, e.g.: cat myfile.json; jq .... myfile.json